# Multiple conditionals with %>%

Tags: r, conditional-statements, magrittr

This seems to be a questions which should be in stackoverflow/google, but it isn't (or at least I couldn't find it) so I will ask it here:

Reproducible example:

```
colnames(df)
"Z1"   "Z2"   "Z3"   "GV1"  "GV2"  "GV3"  "GV4"  "GV5"  "GV6"  "GV7"  "GV8"  "GV9" "GVY"  "EN1" "EN2"  "EN3"  "EN4"  "EN5"  "EN6"  "EN7"  "EN8"  "EN9"  "ENY"  "PV1"  "PV2"  "PV3"  "PV4"  "PV5"  "PV6"  "PV7"  "PVY"
```

I'm trying to understand/do the next code:

```
colnames(df[substr(colnames(df),start=1,stop=2) == "GV" & substr(colnames(df),start=3,stop=3) != "Y"])
```

With magrittr pipe operator `%>%` as I like to use it for a more readable code (this works):

```
library(magrittr)
df %>%
  colnames %>%
    substr(start=1,stop=2) == "GV"
```

However, it doesn't makes sense doing this (this doesn't work):

```
df %>%
  colnames %>%
    substr(start=1,stop=2) == "GV" & substr(colnames(df),start=3,stop=3) != "Y"]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's your ultimate goal?

Comment: Please give a [mcve] in your question!

Comment: Have you tried replacing `colnames(df)` with `.` in `substr(colnames(df),start=3,stop=3) != "Y"` (as well as removing the final `]`)?

Comment: The ultimate goal is simplify the code. Doing the first line of code with magrittr code is the final objective.

Comment: have you tried combinations of `select()` with `contains()` or `starts_with()` ?

Comment: `df %>%
  colnames %>%
    {substr(., start = 1, stop = 2) == "GV" & substr(., start = 3, stop = 3) != "Y"}`

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to *simplify the code* then you can use regular expressions:

```
# Match string that starts with GV and is not fallowed by Y
grep("^GV[^Y]", foo, value = TRUE)
# [1] "GV1" "GV2" "GV3" "GV4" "GV5" "GV6" "GV7" "GV8" "GV9"

# Data
foo <- c("Z1", "Z2", "Z3", "GV1", "GV2", "GV3", "GV4", "GV5", "GV6", "GV7", "GV8", "GV9", "GVY", "EN1", "EN2", "EN3", "EN4", "EN5", "EN6", "EN7", "EN8", "EN9", "ENY", "PV1", "PV2", "PV3", "PV4", "PV5", "PV6", "PV7", "PVY")
```

Comment: @chris did the answer work? Or is there a way I can improve it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to have a more reproducible example, that said, have you tried splitting the filters?

```
df %>%
  colnames %>%
    substr(start=1,stop=2) == "GV"  %>%
       substr(colnames(df),start=3,stop=3) != "Y"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @Pogibas's data you could write your command like this using `{`:

```
foo %>% {substr(.,start=1,stop=2) == "GV" & substr(.,start=3,stop=3) != "Y"}
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [19] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```